# Problem of spacing with numprint and newtxmath packages

Tags: spacing, french, numprint

I have a problem of spacing and it seems to come from these two packages.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}
%\usepackage[np,autolanguage]{numprint}
 
\newcommand*{\fct}[5]{%
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}c@{}c@{}c}
  #1 \colon & #2 & \; \longrightarrow & \; #3 \\ 
            & #4 & \; \longmapsto     & \; #5 
\end{array}}

\begin{document}
  $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$
  
  $\fct{f}{X}{Y}{x}{\sin x}$
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

That's exactly what I want with my command `\fct`: The `:` and `X` are perfectly aligned in both lines. But to get this, I have to comment the `numprint` package. If I do not comment this package, here is the result:

[image]

The `X` has moved to the left. Can someone explain me why and tell me how to modify my `\fct` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not due to `numprint`, but to `array`, that the package loads.

A minimal example is

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\fct}[5]{%
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}c@{}c@{}c}
  #1 \colon & #2 & \; \longrightarrow & \; #3 \\
            & #4 & \; \longmapsto     & \; #5
\end{array}}

\begin{document}
  $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$

  $\fct{f}{X}{Y}{x}{\sin x}$
\end{document}
```

I suggest a better way to define the `\fct` command: you have some spacings on the wrong side.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\fct}[5]{%
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
  #1 \colon {} & #2 & {}\longrightarrow{} & #3 \\
               & #4 & {}\longmapsto{}     & #5
\end{array}}

\begin{document}
  $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$

  $\fct{f}{X}{Y}{x}{\sin x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, egreg. It works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If you change `\colon` to `\colon{}` in the definition of the `\fct` macro, you'll get the same output whether or not the `numprint` package is loaded.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[np,autolanguage]{numprint}

\newcommand*{\fct}[5]{%
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}c@{}c@{}c}
  #1 \colon{} & #2 & \; \longrightarrow & \; #3 \\ 
              & #4 & \; \longmapsto     & \; #5 
\end{array}}

\begin{document}
  $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$
  
  $\fct{f}{X}{Y}{x}{\sin x}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mico. It works perfectly.